# How to Convert a list of tuples into a Json string

Tags: json, erlang, jsx, erlang-shell, jiffy

I have a Erlang list of tuples as follows:

```
[  {{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]}  , 
   {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}  ]
```

I wanted this list of tuples in this form:

```
<<" [  {{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]} , 
       {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}] ">>
```

So I tried using JSON parsing libraries in erlang (both jiffy and jsx )
Here is what I did:

```
A=[  {{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]}  , 
       {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}  ],

B=erlang:iolist_to_binary(io_lib:write(A)),

jsx:encode(B).
```

and I get the following output(here I have changed the list to binary since jsx accepts binary):

```
 <<"[{{[97]},[2],[{3,[98]},{4,[99]}],[5,[100]],[1,1],{e},[[102]]},{{[103]},
 [3],[{6,[104]},{7,[105]}],[{8,[106]}],[1,1,1],{k},[[76]]}]">>
```

jiffy:encode(B) also gives the same output.
Can anyone help me to get the output as :

```
<<" [  {{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]} , 
           {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}] ">>
```

instead of

```
<<"[{{[97]},[2],[{3,[98]},{4,[99]}],[5,[100]],[1,1],{e},[[102]]},{{[103]},
     [3],[{6,[104]},{7,[105]}],[{8,[106]}],[1,1,1],{k},[[76]]}]">>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `io_lib:write(A)`, use `io_lib:format("~p", [A])`. It tries to guess which lists are actually meant to be strings.  (In Erlang, strings are actually lists of integers.  Try it: `"A" == [65]`)

```erlang
> A=[  {{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]}  ,
       {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}  ].
[{{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]},
 {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}]
> B = erlang:iolist_to_binary(io_lib:format("~p", [A])).
<<"[{{\"a\"},[2],[{3,\"b\"},{4,\"c\"}],[5,\"d\"],[1,1],{e},[\"f\"]},\n {{\"g\"},[3],[{6,\"h\"},{7,\"i\"}],[{8,\"j\"}],[1,1,1],{k},[\"L\"]}]">>
```

If you don't want to see the backslashes before the double quotes, you can print the string to standard output:

```erlang
> io:format("~s\n", [B]).
[{{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]},
 {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}]
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Sorry I misunderstood your answer. Now I understood that you suggested to use io:format("~s\n",[B]) separately. But currently I am getting a output like <<"[{{\"a\"},[2],[{3,\"b\"},{4,\"c\"}],[5,\"d\"],[1,1],{e},[\"f\"]},\n {{\"g\"},[3],[{6,\"h\"},{7,\"i\"}],[{8,\"j\"}],[1,1,1],{k},[\"L\"]}]">>. Is there any way to get the data without the slashes but as a binary string like <<" ">>. The option to use io:format("~s\n") also removes <<" ">>, but I want it too. Also I wanted to get rid of the '\n' too that are getting generated.Kindly suggest something

Comment: To get the string without `\n`, you can do something like `io_lib:format("~1000p", [A])` - that will only add newlines if the output is longer than 1000 characters; not sure if there's a way to do it without the limit. You can print it with `io:format("<<\"~s\">>\n", [B])` to get the `<<"` and `">>` markers without escaping the double quotes in the middle.

Comment: thank you @legiscia, using limit is working as of now.

Answer (score 3):

`<<" [  {{"a"},[2],[{3,"b"},{4,"c"}],[5,"d"],[1,1],{e},["f"]} , 
       {{"g"},[3],[{6,"h"},{7,"i"}],[{8,"j"}],[1,1,1],{k},["L"]}] ">>`

This ^^ isn't a valid erlang term, but I think what you're getting at is that you want the "listy" strings, like `"a"` to be printed out like `"a"` instead of `[97]`. Unfortunately, I've found this to be a serious shortcoming of Erlang. The problem is that the string literal `"a"` is only syntactic sugar and is identical to the term `[97]`, so any time you output it, you're subject to the vagaries of "is this thing a string or a list of integers?" The best way I know to get out of that is to use binaries as your strings wherever possible, like `<<"a">>` instead of `"a"`.

Comment: Yes @Ryan Stewart this term is my custom requirement. Thank you for your valuable suggestion.